# Machine level Instruction trace monitoring using QEMU?

Tags: c++, qemu

I have developed  an intel pintool for tracing specific machine level instructions (cmp, ...) of a given program.

Now I found that I should switch this task to QEMU but in fact I didn't have prior experience developing tools based on QEMU and in fact I didn't find much documentations about this.

So, how is possible to trace specific machine instructions with QEMU?

Is it true that I should develop this as a TCG plugin for QEMU or there are other ways to do this?

Thanks!

p.s : I found that this code is doing instruction level tracing as a QEMU TCG plugin :

```
    TCGTemp *args[1];
    TCGv_i64 tcgv_str;
    size_t size = MAX_PRINT_SIZE*sizeof(char);
    size_t left;
    char *str = g_malloc(size);
    char *ptr;
    size_t count;
    int i;

    ptr = str;
    left = size;
    count = snprintf(ptr, left,
                         "0x%"PRIx64":\t %s\t %s\t //",
                         insn->address,
                         insn->mnemonic,
                         insn->op_str);
        for (i = 0; i < insn->size && count < left; i++) {
            left -= count;
            ptr += count;
            count = snprintf(ptr, left, " %02x", insn->bytes[i]);
        }
        if (count < left) {
            left -= count;
            ptr += count;
            snprintf(ptr, left, "\n");
        }
        snprintf(str + size - 5, 5, "...\n");
    
        tcgv_str = tcg_const_i64((uint64_t)(intptr_t)str);
    
        args[0] = tcgv_i64_temp(tcgv_str);
    
        tcg_gen_callN(write_str, TCG_CALL_DUMMY_ARG, 1, args);
    
        tcg_temp_free_i64(tcgv_str);
```

Is it possible to merge the entire code of a TCG plugin into the base of the QEMU so it can be used as a patch of QEMU while running the guest?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. SO is for asking questions about: a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tool commonly used by programmers. It should be a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Your question may be better suited to another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a TCG plugin is your best bet here if you need to do this based on QEMU. The only other approach would end up trying to modify QEMU's own source code, which will be painful and not a maintainable solution in the long term.

It's worth checking whether using QEMU is a hard requirement -- QEMU's main focus is on running guest code quickly, and it has historically not really had support for "instrumentation" of guest code -- the TCG plugin stuff is a fairly recent addition. Depending on what you're doing you might also want to evaluate DynamoRIO or valgrind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the reason behind that I'm using QEMU for this is, the main platform of this specific software is based on QEMU for instrumenting BlackBox binaries. I found PIN much easier to use, but in our experiments, QEMU is about 10x faster than PIN and also its easier for us to apply a patch beside that software patch for QEMU than developing a new base for PIN.

Another question is, is it possible to merge the entire code of a TCG plugin into the base of the QEMU so it can be used as a patch of QEMU while running the guest?

Comment: The point of TCG plugins is that they are separate from QEMU proper and don't require modifications to QEMU itself. You can specify on the QEMU commandline which plugins it should load.